# getting out of for loop

Tags: java, netbeans, for-loop, switch-statement, break

i have written a program to convert character a,g,t,c from a textbox to another value the problem is that when several values apart from a,g,t,c it displays an error message for each invalid character.how can i do it such that on the first invalid character it sees it stop the conversion method.Below are my codes.Thank you

```
private void dna2rna() {
   String DNA = dna_ta.getText();
   char[]readdna;
   readdna=DNA.toCharArray();
   for (int x=0;x<readdna.length;x++){
      switch(DNA.charAt(x))
      {
         case 'A': readdna[x] = 'U';break;
         case 'T': readdna[x] = 'A';break;
         case 'C': readdna[x] = 'G';break;
         case 'G': readdna[x] = 'C';break;
         case 'a': readdna[x] = 'u';break;
         case 't': readdna[x] = 'a';break;
         case 'c': readdna[x] = 'g';break;
         case 'g':readdna[x] = 'c';break;
         default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
               "Not a DNA Sequence.Please Retry",
               "Sequence error",
               JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            dna_ta.setText("");
            rna_ta.setText(""); 
            break;
      }
      String rna= new String(readdna);
      rna_ta.setText(rna);
   }
}
```

the problem is if it finds the the default case it goes out and continue the for loop .how to prevent it from going through the for loop.

Comment: Not my type of business but whoever downvoted this should explain why.

Comment: @Cummander Checkov, I did not downvoted this, but maybe someone did it because of unformatted code that is not compilable.

Answer (score 2):

add a label to the loop, use break wiith this label. kind of goto style, but it works...

```
private void dna2rna() {
    String DNA = dna_ta.getText();
    char[]readdna;
    readdna=DNA.toCharArray();
    forLoop: // <----------- label
    for (int x=0;x<readdna.length;x++){

         switch(DNA.charAt(x))
         {
             case 'A': readdna[x] = 'U';break;
             case 'T': readdna[x] = 'A';break;
             case 'C': readdna[x] = 'G';break;
             case 'G': readdna[x] = 'C';break;
             case 'a': readdna[x] = 'u';break;
             case 't': readdna[x] = 'a';break;
             case 'c': readdna[x] = 'g';break;
             case 'g':readdna[x] = 'c';break;
             default:
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Not a DNA Sequence.Please   Retry","Sequence error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                dna_ta.setText("");
                 rna_ta.setText(""); break forLoop; // <----------- break to label
         }
         String rna= new String(readdna);
         rna_ta.setText(rna);
    }

}
```

simple method for testing:

```
private static void dna2rna() {
    char[] readdna = { 'A', 'T', 'W', 'C', 'T', };
    forLoop: for (int x = 0; x < readdna.length; x++) {

        System.out.println("reading: " + readdna[x]);
        switch (readdna[x]) {
             case 'A': readdna[x] = 'U';break;
             case 'T': readdna[x] = 'A';break;
             case 'C': readdna[x] = 'G';break;
        default:
            System.out.println("some weird value!");
            break forLoop;
        }
    }

}
```

output:

```
reading: A
reading: T
reading: W
some weird value! breaking!
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a flag to signal the `for` loop to exit:

```
private void dna2rna() {
   String DNA = dna_ta.getText();
   char[]readdna;
   readdna=DNA.toCharArray();
   boolean error = false;
   for (int x=0;x<readdna.length && !error;x++){

      switch(DNA.charAt(x))
      {
        case 'A': readdna[x] = 'U';break;
        case 'T': readdna[x] = 'A';break;
        case 'C': readdna[x] = 'G';break;
        case 'G': readdna[x] = 'C';break;
        case 'a': readdna[x] = 'u';break;
        case 't': readdna[x] = 'a';break;
        case 'c': readdna[x] = 'g';break;
        case 'g':readdna[x] = 'c';break;
        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Not a DNA Sequence.Please   Retry","Sequence error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            dna_ta.setText("");
            rna_ta.setText("");
            error = true;
            break; // or possibly: continue;
      }
      String rna= new String(readdna);
      rna_ta.setText(rna);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change your `default` option to `return` instead of `break`. You could also make it throw an `IllegalArgumentException` (or any other Exception you prefer) then handle it in the calling method:

```
default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a DNA Sequence");
```

Then in the caller:

```
try {
    dna2rna();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Not a DNA Sequence.Please   Retry","Sequence error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    dna_ta.setText("");
    rna_ta.setText("");
    // Whatever else you were doing when error==true.
}
```

Comment: I like that answer. It's a step towards loose coupling. Moreover `dna2rna()` should not return `void` but String with text for `rna_ta.setText(returnedRna);`, that way handling data presentation (View) is not that tight coupled with logic computing that data

Comment: Ah, and btw. forgot to add to my previous comment (@Prity Akhal read it please;) ): change this `dna2rna();` to: `dna2rna(dna_ta.getText());` so `private static void dna2rna() {(...)}` will become: `private static void dna2rna(String dna)` :)